# Problems with TermDocumentMatrix function in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm trying to create a *TermDocumentMatrix* using *tm* package, but seem to have encountered difficulties.

The input:

```
trainDF<-as.matrix(list("I'm going home", "trying to fix this", "when I go home"))
```

Goal - creating a TDM from the input: (not all controls parameters listed below)

```
control <- list(
    weight= weightTfIdf, 
    removeNumbers=TRUE, 
    removeStopwords=TRUE, 
    removePunctuation=TRUE,    
    stemWords=TRUE, 
    maxWordLength=maxWordL,
    bounds=list(local=c(minDocFreq, maxDocFreq))
)

tdm<- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(DataframeSource(trainDF)),control = control)
```

The error I get:

```
Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

And the tdm object is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: We can't test it as you've given use objects in the control list that aren't defined.  If I remove those items it runs fine. `list(weight= weightTfIdf, removeNumbers=TRUE, removeStopwords=TRUE, 
    removePunctuation=TRUE, stemWords=TRUE)` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error suggests something is wrong with your choice of minimum and maximum document frequency in the bounds.  For example, the following works:

```
control=list(weighting = weightTfIdf,
             removeNumbers=TRUE, 
             removeStopwords=TRUE, 
             removePunctuation=TRUE, 
             bounds=list(local=c(1,3)))
tdm<- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(DataframeSource(trainDF)), control=control)
```

Note that in the latest versions of TM, To specify a weighting you need to use `weighting = weightTfIdf` rather than `weight = weightTfIdf`.  Similarly, you should use `stemming=TRUE` in your control list to stem words.  I'm not sure that `maxWordLength` is an option currently.  TM will silently ignore invalid options in the control list, so you won't know that something is wrong until you go back to inspect the matrix.

Comment: Above suggestion does not work for me unfortunately, specifically if I use: weighting = weightTfIdf with the warning: In TermDocumentMatrix.SimpleCorpus(x, control) : custom functions are ignored. Anything I can do to resolve? Also why does it say that??

Answer (score 0):

The only way the below code works for me is if I use `VCorpus` instead of `Corpus`. Otherwise I get the `custom functions are ignored` message specifically if I use `weighting = weightTfIdf`, but works ok if I delete it.

Here is working code with TF-IDF weighting:

```
control=list(weighting = weightTfIdf,
             removeNumbers=TRUE, 
             removeStopwords=TRUE, 
             removePunctuation=TRUE, 
             bounds=list(local=c(1,3)))
tdm<- TermDocumentMatrix(VCorpus(DataframeSource(trainDF)), control=control)
```